# Fabric: Failed to retrieve settings from https://settings.crashlytics.com

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I'm trying to use Firebase Crashlytics and looks like imposible.
The firebase setup is done but now I want to use Crashlytics and there is not way to get reports.

This is my setup: (https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started)
[image]
[image]
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: Mike from Firebase here. It's odd you hit that issue and needed to sign up for Fabric. I know you're all set, but if you want to dive deeper, feel free to raise a question via the Firebase support portal: https://firebase.google.com/support/ and reference this thread.

Comment: Was there any resolutions to this?

Comment: @KeithLoughnane I had to sign up on Fabric first. Then I was able to link my fabric account to my Firebase account.

Comment: NEVER post images of code, errors or output! [mcve]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I had to sign up on Fabric first. Then I was able to link my fabric account to my Firebase account.